# How to check if there is already existing record at datarowview?

Tags: c#

```
DataRowView rvTbl;

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dsData1;
bs.DataMember = _sheetname;

Excel.Worksheet _workSheet = (Worksheet)_workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(_sheetIndex);
Range rangerow in _workSheet.UsedRange.Rows
```

Above is the definition

```
bs.CurrencyManager.AddNew();
rvTbl = (DataRowView)bs.CurrencyManager.Current;
ctr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rangerow.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rangerow.Cells[1, i + 1].Value2 != null)
        {
            rvTbl[fLine[ctr]] = rangerow.Cells[1, i + 1].Value2.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rvTbl[fLine[ctr]]));
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    bs.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit();
```

Above is my code that process import file and populate the data, my Question is "Is there way to check if the data is already exist?" What will I do?

Comment: DataRowView or DataView ?!

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour DataRowView

Comment: edit your code with definition of bs , rvTbl and rangerow;

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour Done!

Comment: Your code not clear enough! with rvTbl.Row.ItemArray.Contains("value") can check data of row.

Comment: How about I will put all the codes? lol